# (window).load is not working in an Angular template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'd like to load (and later to resize) a huge SVG within an Angular template. Using (window).load to preload the SVG completely should be work. The resizing method is well bounded in a directive and works:

```
 //angular.element(document).ready(scope.resizableF);
 angular.element($window).bind('load', scope.resizableF);
 angular.element($window).bind('resize', scope.resizableF);
 <div resizable-f="resize" resizable="true">...
```

But unfortunately it seems (window).load event is not working if the SVG is in the template provided. Here is a little plunker to explain: http://plnkr.co/edit/l0miPluX21HHe6fiV4AZ?p=preview

And here are the results (the binding to (window).('resize') is always enabled and it is not the Problem):

-svg is only enabled in index.html && (document).ready() is enabled in the directive: resize() is executed at page load and at resize

-svg is only enabled in index.html && ($window)bind.('load') is enabled in the directive: resize() is executed at page load and at resize

svg is only enabled in content.html && (document).ready() is enabled in the directive, navigate to content: resize() is executed at page load and at resize

-svg is only enabled in content.html && ($window)bind.('load') is enabled in the directive, navigate to content: resize() is executed at resize but NOT at page load

The questions are: How can I use the (window).load if for preloading the SVG within the template (not index.html)? why it works for (window).resize but not for (window).load?

Comment: I'm pretty sure window's `load` event doesn't wait for dynamic content

Comment: I would use a `promise` for this. Preform any actions after it's been resolved.